# What packages or tools best support any 3D line, plane, surface intersections?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, 3d, asymptote

I have not explored the PSTricks' `pst-solides3d`, TikZ's equivalent packages, Asymptote as a tool, etc, yet.

I have a task to make some simple 3D diagrams that are related to 3D geometry subject we learnt in senior high school. For example, we need to find the cross section of a cube cut by any plane, or a point at which a line penetrate a plane, etc.

Which packages or tools do you recommend?

Comment: Asymptote is not a package but it's surely the best tool to create complicated drawings in 3D. Now it's impossible to compare a tool like asymptote with a package like tikz. The first is a drawing tool and the second a fine package to illustrate some results. The choice depends on what you want.

Comment: can _all_ be done with `pst-solides3d` ...

Comment: @Herbert: Is it a question or confirmation because your word ordering seems to be a mix of a question and confirmation pattern?

Comment: @Herbert yes you can do a lot of things with pstricks and pst-solides3d. It is certain that PStricks is more powerful than Tikz to draw 3D pictures but I think the more powerful tool to draw complicated drawings and to do some complicated calculations is Asymptote. Some links to see some results with Asymptote  http://marris.org/asymptote/Surfaces_3D/index.html http://www.marris.org/asymptote/Transformations_3D/index.html and http://www.marris.org/asymptote/Autres_3D/index.html

Comment: @AlainMatthes: How can you compare both? I cannot remember that you tried `pst-solides3d` in the past ;-)  http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pst-solides3d/doc/

Comment: @Herbert I tried but I'm not an expert and now I do not need to draw this kind of drawings (It's very difficult with tikz, it's why sometimes I need a powerful tool). The gallery is very beautiful. I think to answer the question, the better thing is to try pstricks and asymptote. (tikz here is out of the competition, except  for very simple pictures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention that you've been tasked with drawing *simple* 3D structures. For that, a visually intuitive tool is [Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com). 3D geometry for cubes is obtained by extruding (using the Push/Pull tool) a square, and model components can be intersected with one another.

[image]

Geometric perspective to the desired viewpoint is easily achieved via the orbiting tool. Print to PDF provides a means to include the resulting 3D structure to be included into your LaTeX document:

[image]

More complex figures and intersections are also possible using basic constructions of rectangles/circles and extrusions in 3D. Here the two pieces from the intersected cube has been separated:

[image]

Comment: How can we show only the cross section?

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: I've added a view on showing a separation of the cross-section. Not sure whether this is what you're after.

Comment: I am trying the software first whether it support coordinate inputs, math expressions, etc.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: Yes, it accepts coordinate inputs, but not math expressions for curve or line generation.